# Call trigger explicitly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

As we know that sql trigger get called implicitly.
I am just wondering is it possible to call trigger explicitly in sql server?

if yes, than how?

Thanks

Comment: No you can't. And by definition you should not want or need to. If it is truly common logic, place in stored proc or function

Comment: Just a very bad idea to do this, but you could create  a stored proc that does what you want passing the inserted and deleted columns. Then you could call the stored proc directly.

Comment: @PhilBolduc - but that implies you're going to have to use a cursor or similar construct inside the trigger, to be able to pass each row to such a procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose it depends on what you mean by calling the trigger explicitly.

You can cause a trigger to fire with no data changes to the underlying table:

```
create table T (ID int not null)
go
create trigger T_T on T after insert
as
    RAISERROR('Hello',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
go
insert into T(ID)
select 1 where 1=0
```

With the result:

```
Hello

(0 row(s) affected)
```

That being said, it's a bit of a cheat, and in common with @Mitch Wheat, I'm wondering why you'd attempt to do this. If "explicitly calling the trigger" is part of your solution to a problem, then a) It's probably the wrong solution, and b) We might be able to suggest a better one, if we know what the problem is.

Comment: Even if it is not a general case solution as [Mitch wheat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16076/mitch-wheat) mentioned it is a clever workaround =D